# What is Mozilla Location Based Services?

Tags: privacy, geolocation, firefox-for-android, location-services

When I installed Firefox on my phone it gave me the option to enable [Mozilla Location Services](https://location.services.mozilla.com/). What does this actually do? Does it help locate things around you, for example stores? Does it increase accuracy of location? What is the privacy policy? I've red some descriptions of the term but it seems like a bunch of wishy washy babble.

[e.g.](https://blog.mozilla.org/services/2013/10/28/introducing-the-mozilla-location-service/)

> The Mozilla Location Service is an experimental pilot project to
>   provide geolocation lookups based on publicly observable cell tower
>   and WiFi access point information. Currently in its early stages, it
>   already provides basic service coverage of select locations thanks to
>   our early adopters and contributors.

but what does it actually hope to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

It's a Network Positioning Service, it locates your position based on a database of Wi-Fi hotspots, mobile cell towers, and possibly in the future other sensor data. This database is collected through crowdsourcing by Firefox users that has enabled Mozilla Location Service or has installed the dedicated [Mozilla Stumbler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.mozstumbler) app.

It is basically Mozilla's take on geolocation service that is currently provided by Google Location Service on most Android devices. Their objective is to build a public, and more openly accessible, crowd-sourced database for a geolocation service.

Presumably this will be the geolocation service that will be used by Firefox OS and desktop Firefox.

The [Privacy Policy for Mozilla Location Service](https://location.services.mozilla.com/privacy) can be found on their website.